# Slow GET request using the Spring controller

Tags: javascript, performance, spring, tomcat, request

Here are the two ways of implementation, that describe the issue.

The first one is the method that works really slow. It tries to get data from server, but the request is `pending` too long, only after that it returns data and everything's fine (except the terrible synchronous perfomance).

```
asyncMethod: function(doSmth, param) {  
    var resp = $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        url: 'url'
    });
    data = resp.responseText;
    doSmth(param, data);
}
```

Here is the same method, but it's **asynchronous**. The perfomance problem is eliminated here. But it executes the part in success only when page is reloaded. Probably reload stops some executions that were the bottleneck of the previous code sample.

```
asyncMethod: function(doSmth, param) {  
    var resp = $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'url',
        success: function () {
            data = resp.responseText;
            doSmth(param, data);
        }
    });
}
```

I don't need to use asynchronous request, if the synchronous one works fast (but now it doesn't). There seem to be some executions, that make the request remain pending for too long. I don't see the execution that may be a bottleneck. Maybe it's somewhere in the libraries that are used, but no other requests are active when `resp` is being processed.

What are the ways to fix the problem or to analyze it? An advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe the script you are trying to load, is the bottleneck itself? How long does that page take to respond?

Comment: Your second example is the only proper way of performing AJAX. The first example is just JAX (eliminates the point of AJAX) and your third example is just plain wrong - it only works when your alert pauses the script for long enough.

Comment: @HankyPanky The synchronous version about forty seconds, but the server side works not more than one second.

Comment: @JohnDoe Interesting that jquery will add 40 second overhead to a request. Can you double check loading time for your server side script via direct browsing?

Comment: @jbabey Thanks for reply. You are right, but the second one doesn't work properly, which made me to investigate the both AJAX and JAX options.

Comment: Are you sure that the delay isn't just the client waiting for a response? Use the [Chrome Dev Tools Network Panel](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network) To isolate where the delay is occurring.

Comment: @adamb I used this panel, it showed that the problem is in the pending time. Two asynchronous versions don't take so long, but also don't work properly.

Comment: @HankyPanky I checked it that way, it takes about one second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main culprits if a response is sat on "pending" for too long:

- The application code that is fulfulling the ajax request is taking longer than expected
- Simple network latency (not much that can be done about that in the application layer)

If you have access to the code that is fulfilling the request then I'd start there. Also, it's probably not a network issue if this request is taking an unusually long time compared to all your other requests

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the async method like this:

```
asyncMethod: function(doSmth, param) {  
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'url',
        success: function (response, status) {
            doSmth(param, response.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This also gave a long pending, the data was finally returned, but it's not an option. Thanks for reply.

Comment: Hmm, I think you're going to find that the performance issue is network-based and not application. If that is the case then you won't be able to eliminate this performance issue AND have a response to work with, because no delay == no response.

Comment: ... Assuming you don't have control of the code on the other side of the ajax fetch of course. If you do, it may still be an application issue, and the performance can be found on that side of the request...

Comment: I thought about that, but other requests work just fine, also via direct browsing I get the data fast. So I'm not sure what exactly could cause that behavior.

Comment: You were right, the problem was on the server side. I don't completely understand why, but I had to manually force the output to be written out. I saw response in browser, but it was active for too long. Please edit the answer and I'll mark it as the right one.

Comment: Cool - I'll add it as a new answer as it's totally different from my original attempt!